# How to pass a ts variable in html page to ts page then perform some calculation and pass it back to html page?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to take amount to be transacted as input from user deduct it from the wallet of the user and then display the updated wallet. The wallet already is pre-loaded with 100 units of money. But when I run the app only 100 is displayed and the changes are not reflected. what do I do ?
Here is my html code

```
<ion-row>
              <ion-col class="txt2" size="6"  text-left >Company<br><ion-text class="bal">Balance    & gms</ion-text>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col class="text2" size="6" text-right ><ion-item><ion-input type="number" value="{{ wallet }}" [(ngModel)]="wallet"  class="ion-text-end"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
<ion-item class="transact-display">
                <ion-input type="number"  placeholder="Enter amount" [(ngModel)]="amount"  name="amount"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
<ion-button class="transact"  type="submit" expand="block"  (click)="transact()">Transact</ion-button>
```

The ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction',
  templateUrl: './transaction.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction.page.scss'],
})
export class TransactionPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router : Router) {}

  wallet: number = 100;
  amount: number ;
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  transact() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/congratulation');
      this.wallet = this.wallet - this.amount;
      return this.wallet;





  }


}
```

Actual behaviour:
No change in the displayed amount. 100 is only displayed even after the Transact button is clicked.

Expected behaviour:
when the user logs in for the 1st time, 100 should be displayed. When the user transacts amount, say 20, 20 should be deducted from 100 and 80 should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is 2 way data binding framwwork:
Use Angular interpolation:

.html

```
<ion-item>
     {{wallet}}
</ion-item>

<ion-item class="transact-display">
      <ion-input type="number"  placeholder="Enter amount" [(ngModel)]="amount"  name="amount"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-button class="transact"  type="submit" expand="block"  (click)="transact()">Transact</ion-button>
```

.ts

```
wallet: number = 100;
  amount: number ;
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  transact() {
      this.wallet = this.wallet - this.amount;   // this will update wallet automatically. 
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/congratulation');
  }
```

Comment: can you make stackblitz? here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4

Comment: The problem still persists : 100 is displayed even after I click on Transact button. What do I do ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-94wrma

Comment: Thank you @Najam Us Saqib . The amount gets deducted and displayed but when I navigate back to this page 100 is displayed.

Comment: then you have to save it in global state or Localstorage.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Save you deducted amount in Local store. `localStorage.setItem()`